# C# Windows Application: Two Tier Communication Method

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, communication

I am creating a windows application in dotnet framework 4.5. The architecture involves a connection between **Application** and **Central Server** where it communicates to central server and sends data in case of a crash (a crash report is submitted). Also it downloads data from the server.

It's basically a two tier application. I am not sure which method will be best for the communication between these two as per the industry standards as well as acceptable to anti-virus applications.

So far, I have known about Socket communication as well as WCF but not sure if there are other methods or which one is better as per the requirements.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the needs that you have, a web-service is always a good option, since it is very friendly for the network because it usually works in port 80 or 8080 and it has fail-safe mechanisms like exception handling which could make your job allot easier. If you use sockets, you might have problems, since the "network guys" will need to create rules for your application to work, and you still need to handle "manually" all of the connection problems.

I guess it depends on your needs, maybe give some more information so that you can get a more specific answer. In my opinion, I would say to go with the web-service since it is able to send binary data through the network in a safe way and it's more "scallable" (not sure if I translated this word correctly).

You can use both option with the WCF, but maybe you are looking for some other option? Is there any specific needs?